# What's the best way to use wishes in Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

So I've assumed it was better to spend your wishes in batches of 10, but I've seen people online claiming it's either better or doesn't make a difference to use them one at a time. Apparently the pity 4* after 10 wishes is guaranteed whether you use a batch of 10 or one at a time.

Is this true? Is any method superior?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference, besides for speed and flexing your 10-pull.

It's not just a claim, it's literally written in the game that you will get a guaranteed 4 star every 10 pulls and a guaranteed 5 star every 90 pulls (character banner) or 80 pulls (weapon banner).

Here's the relevant text for the current limited banner:

> 5-Star Items For Event Wish - Sparkling Steps: Base probability of
> winning 5-star character = 0.600%; consolidated probability (incl.
> guarantee) = 1.600%; guaranteed to win 5-star character **at least once
> per 90 attempts**.
>
> 4-Star Items For Event Wish - Sparkling Steps: Base probability of
> winning 4-star item = 5.100%; base probability of winning 4-star
> character = 2.550%, and base probability of winning 4-star weapon =
> 2.550%; consolidated probability (incl. guarantee) of winning 4-star item = 13.000%; guaranteed to win 4-star or above item **at least once per 10 attempts**.

[image: Gacha Rules]

There is no mention of 10-pulls - everything is counted per attempt and hence 10-pulls do not affect the guarantee nor odds.

Comment: I don't have first hand experience with this, but say the following happens: a player has had 85 pulls without 5-star character banner. A 10-pull is used. Will the counter for the next one now be on 0, 5, anything in between?

Comment: @Mast it depends what the 5* came on. It is recommended to single pull for efficiency, because you never know what your pity counter will be after that 10 pull. If it came on the first one (86), then you're now 9 into your new pity. It could just as easily have come on the 5 slot (90), which would set it to 5.

Comment: @Mast You can always check your Wish history to see how many pulls you need before your next pity pull, as the history is kept in order, even if you do a 10 pull - it will show where exactly in that ten the 4 star came.

Comment: McLaine reply adds an important point you kinda missed. The game being a gatcha means that the biggest advantage single pulls have is being able to STOP at any pull. This doubles in importance when you consider that the game has multiple banners with different pity counters (an event character banner, an event weapon banner and a standard banner) and not even all the banners use the same currency. Since there is no 10+1 free pull nor increased drop % for doing multi pulls, there is no reason to do so other than time.

Answer (score 9):

There’s no difference in statistics/pity pulls, but if you do 1x pulls then you’re more likely to have some left over after you get the character you want. Say you do a 10x pull on Ganyu’s banner and get her- she could have been the first pull in a line of 10, and now those other 9 wishes are wasted when they could have been used for other banners. Basically just helps to stop while you’re ahead!